# Reporting Services on SharePoint errror

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, reporting-services, reporting

We are using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise with SQL Server 2012. We have recently applied patches to SharePoint and SQL Server (SQL Service Pack 3).

I'm not entirely sure if the updates broke SharePoint reporting as we have now discovered that the reports in SharePoint no longer work, the following error is displayed in SharePoint:

> An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for
>   more details. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException:
>   An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for
>   more details. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingObjectModel,
>   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

I've not familiar with reporting services and would be grateful for assistance

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a call with MS the problem was rectified by changing the execution account to default in Reporting Services. I believe the updates altered the dlls file (or folder) permissions to default

Answer (score 2):

This generally occurred after the SQL Server upgrading or installing a new version beside the current version.

Where the `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingObjectMode` version is changed from `11.0.0.0` to `12.0.0.0` so the `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingObjectModel` DDL file could not be loaded.

To change it back, check the detail steps at [SSRS 2012 REPORT MANAGER CAN’T LOAD MICROSOFT.REPORTINGSERVICES.SHAREPOINT.OBJECTMODEL](https://arcanecode.com/2015/01/28/ssrs-2012-report-manager-cant-load-microsoft-reportingservices-sharepoint-objectmodel/)